# Context API is returning undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a source component in which I am trying to use context api. Below is my code of `SourceComponent.js`. I am trying to fetch the fileType data using the concept of context Api using `useContext`

```
    import React, {useContext} from "react";
    import { MappingData } from "./DataProviders/MappingDataProvider";
    import { Select } from '@appkit/react-components'

    const SourceComponent = () => {
        const CreateMappingData = useContext(MappingData);
        return (
          
            <>
            {console.log('CreateMappingData',CreateMappingData)} // Here the CreateMappingData is undefined in console
                <div>Source</div>
                <div className="form-group">
                <Select
                  data={CreateMappingData.fileType}
                  searchable={true}
                  name="FileType"
                  required={true}
                  placeholder={"File Type"}
                  valueKey={"File Type"}
                  labelKey={"File Type"}
                ></Select>
                </div>
                
            </>
        )
    }

    export default SourceComponent;
```

And then the code of `MappingDataProvider.js` is below

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState, createContext} from "react";

    export const MappingData = createContext();

    export const MappingDataProvider = ({children})=>{
        const [fileType, setFileType] = useState([]);
        
        useEffect(()=> {
            fetchFileType();
        }, [])


        const fetchFileType = () => {
            setFileType([
            { value: 'client', label: 'Client' },
            { value: 'project', label: 'Project' },
            { value: 'user', label: 'User' },
            
        ])
    };
        
        return(
            <MappingData.Provider
            value={
                {fileType}
            }
            >
                {children}
            </MappingData.Provider>
        )
    }
```

Here I am getting `CreateMappingData` as undefined and also `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileType')`

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something below,

**in your source component, replace the line no 5**

```
const {value}= useContext(MappingData);
```

and wrap the main parent component by below

```
<MappingDataProvider> YOUR PARENT COMPONENT </MappingDataProvider>
```

Comment: Rajitha Ganji IN go through this link : https://blog.logrocket.com/react-context-api-deep-dive-examples/